# Authorizing Android ADB on Qualcomm phone from off state

Tags: android, adb, root, recovery, qualcomm

My phone, sharp Aquos 304sh is bootloop because I without knowledge adding bigger value on dalvik cache

Trying to connect data cable on the phone is bootloop state and detect adb unauthorized (because i was reinstalling my PC so many times because a virus), and connecting data cable in off state is same, adb detected unauthorized

Comment: `adb unauthorized` is a security feature that protects your data on the phone from unauthorized access. Unless you manage to boot into UI and acknowledge the adb dialog or manage to find the old adb key from your former PC installation you won't be able to access data (even if the PC is infected you should always perform a full backup before re-installing everything).

Comment: but my phone was in bootloop and I couldn't go to the UI or recovery because the volume button was on screen, not a physical button.

Comment: These are the rules on an unrooted phone. No UI, no adb access.

Comment: my phone was rooted

Comment: On a bootloader unlocked/rooted device you may be able to install/boot into a custom recovery ROM for your device. Some of them have support for accessing the encrypted user data. With full access it should be possible to add your adb key as authorized or directly perform the file operations you want to do.

Comment: but how can i boot into bootloader with the volume button is not physical